# Is Zend Server just APC and Apache munched together into an install?

Tags: php, open-source, caching

I am looking at the Zend Server (PE and CE) and am woundering if its just a frontend for php.ini and automatically has Zend Optimizer which basically is APC(right?) in it or if it would actually be interesting for our development machine. Basically does Zend Server have any special sauce I can't get from opensource caching software and what modules would you use to build something like this yourself. Just get Apache, PHP and APC or use lighttpd with xcache?

EDIT:
Is there an opensource alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always with that type of products, difference is support (**with SLA**) and packaging. It seems that Zend also put some nice frontends.

Comment: Although, it does not happen "always with that type of products".

There *are* open source products where the commercial package adds significant stuff besides support and packaging.

Comment: Ok, s/always/very often/

Answer (score 10):

Zend Server has more features than APC+Apache. It's a PHP application server, that means:
- Monitoring of the PHP execution in a production environment;
- Code Tracing of a PHP event (to debug in a production environment, storing the execution stack of PHP code);
- Debug and profile system;
- Job Queue (to managing a queue of PHP scripts, to schedule the execution of PHP scripts);
- Java Bridge (to call Java classes from PHP); 
- Page Cache (to cache an URL based on conditions $_GET, $_SESSION, $_SERVER, etc);
- Data Cache (an API to cache PHP variables (in disk or in RAM);
- PHP accelerator (a PHP bytecode accelerator, Zend Optimizer+);
- Management of the PHP stack (configuration of PHP, extensions, etc).

The Zend Server Community Edition (CE) is the free version of Zend Server. In this version you have only: 
- Debug and profile system;
- Data Cache (like APC);
- PHP bytecode accelerator, Zend Optimizer+ (like APC);
- Java Bridge;
- Management of the PHP stack.

For more info: http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/

Comment: hmm. i'm still feeling apache+APC+XDEBUG+ any IDE is better. - this way you don't lock yourself down with any proprietary software.

Answer (score 2):

Zend Server has a few interesting features. Zend Optimizer is somewhat faster than APC, if I remember correctly. However, The most unique feature is probably an online remote PHP debugger that integrates with Zend Studio and Zend Studio for Eclipse. Similar solutions are available for free (xdebug is great), but none of those as the same well planned GUI.

It's a stable and well supported package. Wouldn't recommended unless you need support and warranty or is already using Zend Studio, though.